# Simple Form: checkbox's value is always "1"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I have a form and need to add a GDPR checkbox.

If the checkbox is clicked (= checked), the checkbox's value should be `true` (or `1`). If not, then the value should be `false` (or likely `nil`).

This is how I render the checkbox:

```
= f.input :gdpr, as: :boolean, required: true, label: false, checked_value: true, unchecked_value: false, input_html: { }
```

However, when I look at the generated HTML, I see that (probably) by default the checkbox's value is `1` - how is that possible?

EDIT: This is the rendered HTML:

```
<input name="obj[gdpr]" type="hidden" value="open">
<input required="required" aria-required="true" type="checkbox" value="true" name="obj[gdpr]" id="obj_gdpr">
```

How do replaced that `1` with `nil`?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

`value` attribute is not the default value of the checkbox. This attribute is submitted as input's value to the server if checkbox is checked.

E.g.

```html
<label>Completed?</label>
<input type="checkbox" value="completed" name="status">
```

This will be submitted as `status=completed`.

To check if checkbox is checked use `checked` attribute of DOM node in JS.

Also see MDN explanation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/checkbox#value